# Superconductivy and Bethe-Goldstone equation

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, superconductivity, fermions

I'm studying superconductivity with bethe goldstone equation. I have a question about a little thing and I will not see my professor until friday.

In order to understand and give an explanation of cooper pair we have began in this way:

Consider the schrodinger equation for two fermions in the Fermi sea:

$$[T_1 + T_2 + \lambda V(1,2) ] |\psi(1,2)\rangle = E |\psi(1,2)\rangle  $$

Call $|\phi_n \rangle$ the eigenstate of free Hamiltonian $H_0$:

$$H_0 |\phi_n(1,2) \rangle = (T_1 +T_2 ) |\phi_n(1,2)\rangle =E_n   |\phi_n(1,2)\rangle$$

Now we can write $|\psi\rangle$ in this way:

$$|\psi\rangle = |\phi_0 \rangle + \sum\limits_{n\neq 0} |\phi_n \rangle \frac{1}{E-E_n} \langle\phi_n | \lambda V| \psi \rangle $$

$$E-E_0 = \langle \phi_0 | \lambda V | \psi \rangle$$

It is easy to prove the first sentence using the second sentence ( calculate $(H_0 - E) |\psi\rangle$)

But my question is:is $E-E_0 = \langle \phi_0 | \lambda V | \psi \rangle$ true? I am not able to prove it and my professor take it as something true or that we impose.

Comment: What do you get if yo hit your original Schr equation with $\langle \phi_0|$ ?

Comment: @CosmasZachos  $(E-E_0) \langle \phi_0 | \psi \rangle = \langle \phi_0 | \lambda V | \psi \rangle $

Comment: So the bra|ket on the left is unity, no?

Comment: @CosmasZachos If we use $ |\psi\rangle = |\phi_0 \rangle + \sum\limits_{n\neq 0} |\phi_n \rangle \frac{1}{E-E_n} \langle\phi_n | \lambda V| \psi \rangle $ yes is unity. But we have proved that equation through $  (E-E_0) \langle \phi_0 | \psi \rangle = \langle \phi_0 | \lambda V | \psi \rangle$.

Comment: No we have not. To order $\lambda$, $\psi$ is $\phi_0$. Read up on Sakurai-Napolitano.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I have studied quantum mechanics, is something that can be explained in few lines? Or can you give me more precise link ?  I have not that book

Comment: @CosmasZachos I have found the book, can you tell me where it is explained? I have studied most of the things explained by this book

Comment: (5.1.18) et seq.

Comment: @CosmasZachos  Thank you